# How can I get data from Azure Mobile services

Tags: java, android, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to get some data from azure MS sql database with azure mobile services. I wrote the code as like below but when I call the method it is returns null. Where am I doing wrong? What is the query that I should use?

```
private void refreshNumsFromTable() {


    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        mPhonesTable.where().field("PhoneNumber").execute(new TableQueryCallback<PhoneNumbers>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(final List<PhoneNumbers> result, int count,Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) 
                            {

                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        mAdapter.clear();
                                        for(PhoneNumbers num : result)
                                        {
                                            mAdapter.add(num);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                createAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();

}
```

Comment: provide me the link from where you get this code

Comment: why? I wrote the code. It's like msdn samples https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-android-get-started-users/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a complete predicate there. By using the `where()` method, you're asking for results where PhoneNumber meets some criterion, but you aren't specifying that criterion. You need to say that it's equal to something (`eq()`) or that it starts with some string:

`mPhonesTable.where().field("PhoneNumber").eq("555-555-5555").execute().get();`
or
`mPhonesTable.where().startsWith("PhoneNumber", "555").execute().get();`

If you're trying to just return the PhoneNumber column, then use the `select()` method:

`mToDoTable.select("PhoneNumber").execute().get();`

For more information, please see the Mobile Services Android SDK reference:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#querying